# Viewbag in a DisplayTemplate

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, viewbag

How can I pass/send a ViewBag to my DisplayTemplates? I can't use a ViewModel for this so I think on ViewBags...
For example:

Part of my view:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Car)
```

Car.cshtml (displayTemplate):

```
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { Name = modelFieldInitialName + "Name", id = modelFieldInitialId + "Name" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Brand, new SelectList(ViewBag.Brands, "Description", "Description"), "", new { Name = modelFieldInitialName + "Brand", id = modelFieldInitialId + "Brand" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Brand)
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ViewBag` is available in the View without you passing it in. If you add something to `ViewBag` in the Controller, it will be available in the View.

```
//Controller

public ActionResult Test()
{
   ViewBag.Message = "Hello World";
   return View();
}

//In The View

@if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.Message))
{
  <p>ViewBag.Message</p>
}
```

Comment: that seems to work to DisplayTemplates but don't work to a partialView appended to the view by an user action. You know how solve it?

Comment: That's because the partial view is being loaded into an existing view async. In that instance I would either have the data in the ViewModel or grab it with JQuery (or JS). What are you doing that you don't think a ViewModel can handle?

Comment: I'm creating a dynamic table here when the user want create a new table row is appended a specific partial view to it (so I can't use a viewModel for that), and how I have to call a wcf service to populate some dropdownlists I don't want to call the service everytime I create a new partial view

Comment: Can't you store the WCF service result in JavaScript?